# JavaFX ComboBox: Pop-up is getting shifted when screen is full size

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-11

I am struggling now for a long time with the following issue:

I created a `ComboBox` that looks perfectly fine as long as the screen is not full size, see picture

[image: comboBox, screen not in full size]

But if I full size the screen then the Pop-up is getting shifted, see picture below.

[image: image comboBox, screen in full size]

Has anybody any idea what might be the issue?

Environment details: Java 11.06, Windows 10, Intellij Idea Community Version

Here is the code:

```xml
<ComboBox fx:id="comboTokenType" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Test 1" />
            <String fx:value="Test 2" />
            <String fx:value="Test 3" />
            <String fx:value="Test 4" />
            <String fx:value="Test 5" />
            <String fx:value="Test 6" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
    <value>
        <String fx:value="Test 5" />
    </value>
    <GridPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
    </GridPane.margin>
</ComboBox>
```

```css
.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-white-color;
}
.combo-box-popup .list-view{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
   /* -fx-padding: 4 0 4 5;*/
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.combo-box-base{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0; /* 2 */
}
.combo-box-base:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}
.combo-box-base:focused{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}
.combo-box-base:selected{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}
.combo-box-base:showing{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}
.combo-box-base .arrow {
    -fx-shape: "M8.124,13.625l4.125-3.375v2.889l-4.125,3.86L4,13.139V10.25L8.124,13.625z";
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
}
```

## Update

I tested the ComboBox without my custom code but I still getting this issue.

## Again Update

I created now a small JavaFX project and removed everything that is actually not needed, just the FXML page with the comboBox. It turns out that comboBox is now working perfectly fine. I think the issue needs to be outside this FXML page. Maybe I need to dive deeper into the BorderPane that builds up the entire page.

I am going to publish the result as soon as I found the issue.

Here is the code:

fxml_example.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>

<ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <content>
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
            <Separator halignment="LEFT" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowSpan="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Separator>
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" text="Test 1" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowSpan="1">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="50.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" text="Test 2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="20.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <RadioButton alignment="CENTER_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Test 3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <toggleGroup>
                    <ToggleGroup fx:id="format" />
                </toggleGroup>
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton alignment="CENTER_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Test 555" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <toggleGroup>
                    <fx:reference source="format" />
                </toggleGroup>
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </RadioButton>
            <Label text="Test 5" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="20.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER">
                <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <String fx:value="Test 1" />
                        <String fx:value="Test 2" />
                        <String fx:value="Test 3" />
                        <String fx:value="Test 4" />
                        <String fx:value="Test 5" />
                        <String fx:value="Test 6" />
                    </FXCollections>
                </items>
                <value>
                    <String fx:value="Test 1" />
                </value>
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </ComboBox>
            <Text styleClass="table-label" text="Test 8" textAlignment="RIGHT" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="50.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Text>
            <Separator GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.rowSpan="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Separator>
            <Label graphicTextGap="10.0" text="Test 9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="20.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </TextField>
            <Label text="Test 10" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="10">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="20.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="10">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </PasswordField>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="TEXT_ONLY" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Test 11" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="10" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="80.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="10">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </PasswordField>
            <Text styleClass="table-label" text="Test 15" textAlignment="RIGHT" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="13">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="50.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Text>
            <Separator GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="13" GridPane.rowSpan="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Separator>

            <Label text="Test 18" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="15">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="20.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="15">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </PasswordField>
            <Label text="Test 25" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.rowIndex="15">
                <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="20.0" top="5.0" />
                </HBox.margin>
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="80.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="15">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </PasswordField>
            <Label text="Test 111" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="18">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="50.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Separator GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="18" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Separator>
            <Label style="-fx-text-alignment: center;" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="19" />

            <Button defaultButton="true" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Test 123" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="19">
                <graphic>
                    <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                        <image>
                            <Image url="@background.jpg" />
                        </image>
                    </ImageView>
                </graphic>
                <GridPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="NEVER" prefWidth="300.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="10.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="NEVER" />
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="NEVER" />
                <ColumnConstraints />
                <ColumnConstraints />
                <ColumnConstraints />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <padding>
                <Insets left="30.0" right="30.0" />
            </padding>
            <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@ any css" />
            </stylesheets>
        </GridPane>
    </content>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
</ScrollPane>
```

FXMLExample.java

```
package fxmlexample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLExample extends Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(FXMLExample.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));
        
        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the display is different only when in full-screen mode, that would seem to be a bug in the underlying JavaFX library implementation on the platform you are using (Java 11 on Windows 10).  Try using the most recent version of Java+JavaFX and see if you still have an issue.  If the issue persists, consider filing a [bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report).

Comment: Check first the action of the combo-box without any custom CSS, to see if that works as expected (update the question to report the result of your findings).  If the issue only appears with your custom CSS, consider ditching the parts of your custom CSS which cause the issue to manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I followed your instructions and updated my question. I need now to invest more time to investigate the whole FXML structure (BorderPane with FXML include).

Answer (score 1):

I use Debian 11 with XFCE. I noticed a similar issue when using multiple monitors. In my opinion it's something related to different monitors with different resolutions. My primary screen is FHD and secondary is 2K. So if I set the 2K monitor as primary the combobox is popping up in the correct position.